# Sorted array except for last element

Tags: sorting, insertion-sort

Given an already sorted array of n distinct elements where only the last element is out of order, would insertion sort be the fastest algorithm to be used here?

```
Ex: [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was an array, yes, insertion sort.

Worst case complexity: O(n)

Worst case scenario: Unsorted element is the smallest element.

If it was a linked list of any kind where the cost of insertion is constant time, then a binary search would be the fastest most efficient way.

Worst case complexity: O(log(n))